# Can't deploy docker stack with compose file version 2.4

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I am trying to deploy my docker stack using compose file. When I deploy with compose file version 3+, the deploy works perfectly fine. But when I am trying to use the 2.4 version or lower I get this error:
`unsupported Compose file version: 2.4`

I need to use the 2.4 version, because Version 3 and higher does not support several parameters I need for my containers (such as `cpuset` and `runtime`).

My version of docker is 19.03.6 and docker-compose is 1.25.4.

Is there any way to deploy with an older version of compose file on Docker 19.03.6? Am I missing something or is the latest docker version does not support the older compose files anymore?

**UPDATE**

It turns out that docker 19.03.6 supports only Version 3+ in deploy. So I can't use anything but Version 3+, which does not provide the same flexibility as V2.4 in terms of CPU usage setup. The only solution in this situation (when you need parameters like `cpuset` and `runtime`) would be to run containers manually or move to something like Kubernetes.

Here are compose files examples:

**Version 3.7 (working)**

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ~/ProcessingServerData/mongodb/db:/data/db
      - ~/ProcessingServerData/mongodb/configdb:/data/configdb
    networks:
      - proc-net
    
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - proc-net
  
  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
    ports:
      - 8082:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - proc-net
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

networks:
  proc-net:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

**Version 2.4 (not working)**

```
version: '2.4'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ~/ProcessingServerData/mongodb/db
        target: /data/db
      - type: bind
        source: ~/ProcessingServerData/mongodb/configdb
        target: /data/configdb
    networks:
      - proc-net
    deploy:
      resources:
        cpuset: 0,1
    
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - proc-net
    deploy:
      resources:
        cpuset: 0,1
  
  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
    ports:
      - 8082:8080
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /var/run/docker.sock
        target: /var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - proc-net
    deploy:
      resources:
        cpuset: 0,1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

networks:
  proc-net:
    driver: overlay
```

Comment: The point of the version 3 format is that some options are not supported with swarm mode, so those options are removed in version 3 and swarm mode requires that version for the features it supports.

Answer (score 0):

`deploy` config option is not supported in 2.4 , you need to change the file to this one

```
version: '2.4'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ~/ProcessingServerData/mongodb/db
        target: /data/db
      - type: bind
        source: ~/ProcessingServerData/mongodb/configdb
        target: /data/configdb
    networks:
      - proc-net

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - proc-net

  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
    ports:
      - 8082:8080
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /var/run/docker.sock
        target: /var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - proc-net

networks:
  proc-net:
    driver: overlay
```

Comment: Sadly this is not a solution for my problem. According to this post only Version 3+ is supported for deploy on a newer docker version:
https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-deploy-stack-with-compose-file-version-2-4-on-docker-19-03-6/90119

Comment: You can not use the `deploy` with 2.4,  here you have only two options. 1- use 2.4 and get rid of the `deploy` part, 2- upgrade to v3

Comment: Yes, I understand it now. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no support for an older compose file version for deploy.
https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-deploy-stack-with-compose-file-version-2-4-on-docker-19-03-6/90119